# Please help me with getting ID from JSTREE

Tags: jstree

This is the last resort to me to deal with this.

The problem is I can not get the specific values from the sample data below.

I am in a hurry so it would be very appreciated if you give me any answer to this problem.

This is the code I have.

```
  $("#organize").jstree(
  {
      "core": {'animation': 100},
      "json_data": {
          "data": [
          {
              "data": "J",
              "id": "10600_10600",
              "metadata": {
                  "id": "10600_10600",
                  "name": "10600_10600"
              }
          }]
      },
      "themes": {
          "theme": "classic",
          "url": "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/approval/css/jstree.css"
      },
      "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]

  }).bind("dblclick.jstree", function (e)
  {
      alert($('#organize').jstree('get_selected').attr('id'));
      ////////////TODO: Can not get ID here/////////////////
  });


  $('#add').click(function ()
  {

      //HERE I can get 'name' of the selected node but 'id' is undefined.
      var name = $("#organize").jstree('get_selected').text();
      var id = $("#organize").jstree('get_selected').attr('data');

  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JS tree uses the "attr" JSON property to append attributes and values to nodes. so change your  data section to look like this:

```
$("#organize").jstree(
  {
      "core": {'animation': 100},
      "json_data": {
          "data": [
          {
              "data": "J",
              "attr": {
                  "id": "10600_10600",
                  "name": "10600_10600"
              }
          }]
      },
      .....
```

Comment: Yeah, Exactly. How can I say thank you. Working perfectly!! You saved my life today.

Comment: Just tick the green "V" mark next to the answere so other people can see the answer and if you want to say thank you feel free to vote up ;)

Comment: I'd like to, but it requires some reputation :) Thank you very much~!